# R: Error looping variable in in ggplot2 geom_line

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, line

I am trying to add multiple lines to a plot using a for loop. Using i as a variable to navigate in my data, for some reason, I get an error in the ggplot part all of a sudden, saying that that object i is not found ("Error in as.name(names(data$SURF)[i]) : object 'i' not found"). It seems like only those variables are accepted, that are linked to the data frame given to ggplot. I have used different variables in ggplots before though, so I don't know why it doesn't work now. This is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)

  #creating object 'data' for example purpose
  surf <- list()
  day <- c(1:7)
  for(i in 1:5){
    surf[[i]] <- data.frame(day*i, day-i)
    names(surf)[i] <- paste("var",i,sep = "")
    colnames(surf[[i]]) <- c("T0", "whatever")
  }

  data <- list(surf)
  names(data)[1] <- "SURF"
  df <- data.frame(day)
  ret <- ggplot(df, aes(x=day))
  for(i in 1:length(names(data$SURF))){
    df[,i+1] <- data$SURF[[i]]$T0
    colnames(df)[i+1] <- names(data$SURF)[i]
    ret <- ret + geom_line(data = df, aes(y=as.name(names(data$SURF)[i]), colour= names(data$SURF)[i]))
  }
```

I managed to solve the problem in a not fully pleasing way, by omitting new variables in the plot part. I am not fully content with this solution though, because I want to keep working from a more automated code. This is the 'dirty" solution:

```
  df <- data.frame(day)
  ret <- ggplot(df, aes(x=day))
  for(i in 1:length(names(data$SURF))){
    df$y <- data$SURF[[i]]$T0
    df$name <- names(data$SURF[i])
    ret <- ret + geom_line(data = df, aes(y=y, colour= name))
  }
```

I'd be grateful if someone could help me figure out why the use of 'external' variable i does not work in this example.

Comment: Why are you looping? Generally in ggplot, if you are either looping or adding the same element to your plot multiple times you're not doing it right and massaging your data into another format is the better solution.

Comment: I think you might save yourself a lot of pain if you instead reshaped your multiple columns into a dat-value and grouping column using a package such as `reshape` or `tidy` and then used ggplot as intended `colour=grouping_column`

Comment: @StephenHenderson, how exactly do I group my data into a dat-value and a grouping column then? Sorry, if this is an unnecessary question, but I just don't know how.

Comment: your code does not compile....please show the minimal amount of `dput` output of your data frame that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @pcantalupo, sorry I didn't. Now I added a quick example that is enough for this purpose (see code above).

Comment: @oepix look into the reshape2-package. You could use `melt(yourdata, measure.vars=c(vector_with_columns_you_want_to_plot)`

Comment: Look [here](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf) for data wrangling hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I see, my head was thinking in the wrong direction and way too complicated. Using the melt() function of the reshape2 package really gives me everything I need for this purpose. For anyone interested, here is how I solved my problem:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

for(i in 1:length(data$SURF)){
    df[,i+1] <- data$SURF[[i]]$T0
}
colnames(df) <- c("day", names(data$SURF))
mlt <- melt(data = df, id.vars = "day")
ret <- ggplot(mlt) +
    aes(x=day, y=value, group=variable, colour = variable) +
    geom_line()
```